# AttributeError when tokenizing sentence

Tags: python, string, nltk, tokenize, attributeerror

When I tried the following code:

```
tok_corp= [nltk.word_tokenize(sent.decode('utf-8')) for sent in corpus]
```

I get an `AttributeError`:

> 'float' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Given that error, your `sent` variable likely contains a float value, rather than the string you seem to expect. Test that your `corpus` looks as you expect, separate from the other operations. Show more detail here about how `corpus` is constructed and some example entries.

Answer (score 0):

Before chaining everything up into a one-liner, try checking your object types, e.g.

```
for sent in corpus:
    print(type(sent), sent)
```

You should see that something is a `float` inside there.

Next `str.decode('utf8')` is sort of dangerous. If you're in Python3, utf8 should be the default, so it's not necessary if your in Python2, somewhere in your code, there should be an `open()`, instead of using the default `open()` in Python2, specific the encoding using `io.open()`, e.g.

```
import io

with io.open('somefile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    corpus = fin.read().split('\n')
```

That way, everything read as the `fin` object, would be by default a `str`/`unicode` type, so `.decode('utf8') isn't needed.